# How to get pixel value from a widow in graphics.py python?

Tags: python, graphics

I am using graphics.py to display elements in a window. Is there a way to get pixel value from a window once we draw on it?

There's a getPixel method but for an Image object. I tried drawing an Image onto a window and then draw other element onto the image but the getPixel only returns original returns original pixel value.

Comment: It seems pygame is a better alternative if one needs pixel value.